# Is there a way to set up a special user for kvm administration without adding to wheel group?

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, permissions

I'm trying to set up a user to manage kvm machines on a server, but I wanted to know if it would be possible to do without adding the user to the wheel group, as that effectively grants them administrator privileges.

Comment: Are you using libvirt, or just kvm on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question. The problem I had was with policykit not recognizing the policy I had created allowing users in the kvm group to manage virtual machines. I updated all packages and rebooted the system and that fixed it.

For other users reading this trying to create the same effect, create a group called kvm and add kvm administrator(s) to it. Then, use policykit to create a rule granting access to kvm using the following line:

```
Action=org.libvirt.unix.manage
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use the file /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf, if the group libvirt doesn't exist, create it
    uncomment #unix_sock_group = "libvirt" in /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf

If you want your users can use virt-manager you need to configure polkit, for more information about polkit

```
  http://libvirt.org/auth.html
```